# THREE.js orthographic camera zoom to mouse point

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, zooming

I'm working on an orthographic camera for our THREE.js app. Essentially, this camera will present the scene to the user in 2D (users have the option of switching between the 2D and 3D camera). This camera will allow for panning and zooming to mouse point. I have the panning working, and I have zooming working, but not zooming to mouse point. Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import T from 'three';

let panDamper = 0.15;

let OrthoCamera = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      distance: 150,
      position: { x: 8 * 12, y: 2 * 12, z: 20 * 12 },
    };
  },
  getThreeCameraObject: function () {
    return this.camera;
  },
  applyPan: function (x, y) { // Apply pan by changing the position of the camera
    let newPosition = {
      x: this.state.position.x + x * -1 * panDamper,
      y: this.state.position.y + y * panDamper,
      z: this.state.position.z
    };

    this.setState({position: newPosition});
  },
  applyDirectedZoom: function(x, y, z) {
    let zoomChange = 10;
    if(z < 0) zoomChange *= -1;
    let newDistance = this.state.distance + zoomChange;

    let mouse3D = {
      x: ( x / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
      y: -( y / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1
    };

    let newPositionVector = new T.Vector3(mouse3D.x, mouse3D.y, 0.5);
    newPositionVector.unproject(this.camera);
    newPositionVector.sub(this.camera.position);

    let newPosition = {
      x: newPositionVector.x,
      y: newPositionVector.y,
      z: this.state.position.z
    };

    this.setState({
      distance: newDistance,
      position: newPosition
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    let position = new T.Vector3(this.state.position.x, this.state.position.y, this.state.position.z);

    let left = (this.state.distance / -2) * this.props.aspect + this.state.position.x;
    let right = (this.state.distance / 2) * this.props.aspect + this.state.position.x;
    let top = (this.state.distance / 2) + this.state.position.y;
    let bottom = (this.state.distance / -2) + this.state.position.y;

    // Using react-three-renderer
    // https://github.com/toxicFork/react-three-renderer
    return <orthographicCamera
      {...(_.pick(this.props, ['near', 'far', 'name']))}
      position={position}
      left={left}
      right={right}
      top={top}
      bottom={bottom}
      ref={(camera) => this.camera = camera}/>
  }
});

module.exports = OrthoCamera;
```

Some zooming towards the mouse point happens but it seems erratic. I want to keep a 2D view, so as I zoom, I also move the camera (rather than having a non-perpendicular target, which kills the 2D effect).

I took cues from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994206/zoom-to-object-in-threejs/30514984#30514984). As far as I can tell, I am successfully converting to THREE.js coordinates in `mouse3D` (see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036106/three-js-projector-and-ray-objects)).

So, given this setup, how can I smoothly zoom to the mouse point (`mouse3D`) using the orthographic camera and maintaining a two dimensional view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle to try out code?

Comment: So the problem is camera rotation in process of zooming?

Comment: Have you found the solution Scott H

Comment: Here is a typescript function for zooming an ortho. cam to the pointer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52824008/three-js-orthographiccamera-zoom-to-cursor#76450096

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a camera that is described by a position and a look-at (or pivot) point in world coordinates, zooming at (or away from) a specific point is quite simple at its core.

Your representation seems to be even simpler: just a position/distance pair. I didn't see a rotation component, so I'll assume your camera is meant to be a top-down orthographic one.

In that case, your look-at point (which you won't need) is simply `(position.x, position.y - distance, position.z)`.

In the general case, all you need to do is move both the camera position and the look-at point towards the zoom-at point while preserving the camera normal (i.e. direction). Note that this will work regardless of projection type or camera rotation. EDIT (2020/05/01): When using an orthographic projection, this is not all you need to do (see update at the bottom).

If you think about it, this is exactly what happens when you're zooming at a point in 3D. You keep looking at the same direction, but you move ever closer (without ever reaching) your target.

If you want to zoom by a factor of 1.1 for example, you can imagine scaling the vector connecting your camera position to your zoom-at point by 1/1.1.

You can do that by simply interpolating:

```
var newPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
newPosition.x = (orgPosition.x - zoomAt.x) / zoomFactor + zoomAt.x;
newPosition.y = (orgPosition.y - zoomAt.y) / zoomFactor + zoomAt.y;
newPosition.z = (orgPosition.z - zoomAt.z) / zoomFactor + zoomAt.z;
```

As I said above, in your case you won't really need to update a look-at point and then calculate the new distance. Your new distance will simply be:

```
var newDistance = newPosition.y
```

That should do it.

It only gets a little bit more sophisticated (mainly in the general case) if you want to set minimum and maximum distance limits both between the position/look-at and position/zoom-at point pairs.

UPDATE (2020/05/01):

I just realized that the above, although correct (except for missing one minor but very important step) is not a complete answer to OP's question. Changing the camera's position in orthographic mode won't of course change the scale of graphics being rendered. For that, the camera's projection matrix will have to be updated (i.e. the left, right, top and bottom parameters of the orthographic projection will have to be changed).

For this reason, many graphics libraries include a scaling factor in their orthographic camera class, which does exactly that. I don't have experience with ThreeJS, but I think that property is called 'zoom'.

So, summing everything up:

```
var newPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
newPosition.x = (orgPosition.x - zoomAt.x) / zoomFactor + zoomAt.x;
newPosition.y = (orgPosition.y - zoomAt.y) / zoomFactor + zoomAt.y;
newPosition.z = (orgPosition.z - zoomAt.z) / zoomFactor + zoomAt.z;
myCamera.zoom = myCamera.zoom * zoomFactor
myCamera.updateProjectionMatrix()
```

If you want to use your orthographic camera class code above instead, you will probably have to change the section that computes left, right, top and bottom and add a scaling factor in the calculation. Here's an example:

```
var aspect = this.viewportWidth / this.viewportHeight
var dX     = (this.right - this.left)
var dY     = (this.top   - this.bottom) / aspect
var left   = -dX / (2 * this.scale)
var right  =  dX / (2 * this.scale)
var bottom = -dY / (2 * this.scale)
var top    =  dY / (2 * this.scale)
mat4.ortho(this.mProjection, left, right, bottom, top, this.near, this.far)
```