# THREE.js fit Orthographic camera to scene

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I've searched through many related questions on stack overflow, but I couldn't quite find the answer to this problem.

I have a big, dynamic group of Object3D's in my scene, with an orthographic camera looking at them head-on.

I want to have a simple function which, when called, will simply match the top/left/bottom/right/zoom properties of the Orthographic camera to properly fit the Object3D group.

I've tried all kinds of things, but none of my code is worth posting. I need to look at this from a whole new angle (pun intended). I have found various other answers which discuss changing the fov of the camera, once you know the distance from the face of bounding box of the group to the camera, but I don't know how to implement that with an orthographic camera, since (as far as I've tried) the fov property doesn't work with it (maybe it actually does, I just don't know).

So I don't particularly like asking for code, but nevertheless I would like a function which would automatically adjsut the appropriate properties of the Orthographic camera to fit the object passed to it as a parameter, for example:

```
function fitOrthographicCameraToObject3DGroup(group) {
    //implement here (my question)
}
```

Comment: have you used the scene bounding box dimensions in you computations?

Comment: Yes I am able to compute the compound bounding box of all of the objects in the scene; however, I still have no idea how to automatically adjust the top/left/bottom/right/zoom properties of the orthographic camera based on that.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558085/three-js-orthographic-camera/17567292#17567292) for an explanation of what the `OrthographicCamera` parameters represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the top/left/bottom/right of the orthographic camera once you have the bounding box should not be a problem. Just take the half lengths of the bounding box.

The zoom is the issue and for that you can confine your scene in a unit cube by scaling up or down your scene by the appropriate amount depending on your bounding box size. Then you dont have to worry about the zoom and the above top/left/bottom/right values become 0.5/0.5/-0.5/-0.5.

Comment: How do you suggest aligning the camera to the group once I have the frustrum at the right dimensions?

Comment: And also of the group fit into a unit cube, shouldn't the frustrum be .5/.5/-.5,-.5?

Comment: you said you are looking at the scene head on so I assumed the camera is on the z-axis so no alignment is necessary. updated for second comment.

Comment: That is true, I retract my comment :)

Answer (score 7):

Calculate the bounding box of your mesh and apply this code.
This works for me

```
        var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(container.offsetWidth / -2, container.offsetWidth / 2, container.offsetHeight / 2, container.offsetHeight / -2, 100, 100000);

        //For centering the meshGroup
            var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(meshGroup);
            box.center(meshGroup.position);
            meshGroup.localToWorld(box);
            meshGroup.position.multiplyScalar(-1);

       //For fitting the object to the screen when using orthographic camera

           Camera.zoom = Math.min(container.offsetWidth / (box.max.x - box.min.x),
                container.offsetHeight / (box.max.y - box.min.y)) * 0.4;
           Camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
           Camera.updateMatrix();
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I was going a bit crazy trying to find some approach that worked for OrthographicCamera!

Comment: What if I am looking top down to a plane. box.max.y-box.min.y will be 0. The solution doesn't look generic.